# Getting weird CORS errors with s3, cloudfront, elastic beanstalk nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, network-load-balancer

I have a static S3 website with ssl and cloudfront and a backend on EBS on nginx.

I am getting the following error:

From browser console logs:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mywebsite.com (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

From network tab:

[image]

When calling the same endpoint directly through postman it works fine.
I also have an INTG environment that is http s3 site pointing to an http backend and that also works fine

The issue is only in my main env where I have the s3 site pointing to my domain https://mywebsite.com with cloudfront in front of it for caching and ssl. It points to my backend which is https://api.mywebsite.com that also has an ssl cert on a network load balancer.

Here is my cloudfront config:
[image]

cache policy:

[image]

Origin Request policy:

[image]

This is my nginx config (.platform -> nginx -> conf.d -> proxy.conf)
[image]

From my spring boot app I have allowed the following headers:
"Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "Accept",
"Origin"

and I have also allowed all origins (for the purpose of this test but I don't think this was the problem)

I am at a loss here

Tried allowing some cors settings from the s3 bucket itself but that didn't work. I think cors error is a red hearing and there is some networking issue under the hood that I can't pin point

Comment: `Tried allowing some cors settings from the s3 bucket itself` yes this should be the way, yet no details are provided. Are the issues reading resources from your app (missing headers in the response) ir from S3? Could you show the request/response headers from the preflight req?